# What is a voltage divider?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

I bought two switch relays and connected them up to my Raspberry Pi. I can turn any device on and off, at will.

This person online has a more complicated schematic:

https://www.circuitbasics.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Arduino-Temperature-Dependent-Light-Bulb-With-5V-Relay-Updated.png

[image]

He says:

> The thermistor part of the circuit is set up as a voltage divider. The value of the resistor should be the same order of magnitude as the thermistor. For example, I’m using a 10K Ω thermistor, so the resistor should be 10K Ω as well. If you use a 100K Ω thermistor, use a 100K Ω resistor.

What is a voltage divider?

I am trying to follow the wires on the breadboard and it's doing my head in.

Do I need to know about voltage dividers, and if I wanted to, is there a simple practical guide about them?

Comment: In my opinion the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) for a voltage divider is pretty good at showing the basic math and justifying it - if there's anything there that we can clarify, please [edit] your post to let us know. If you can find a proper schematic on the same site as that wiring diagram, it may be much easier to see the voltage divider as a subset of it. The intersecting wires are not helpful, but if you focus on just the thermistor, resistor, and red/blue/black wires between there and the Arduino (and ignore the relay) you should see the divider.

Comment: Here's a tip: don't use those awful wiring diagrams to try to understand circuits. Use a proper schematic.

Comment: Note: There is no relationship between the relay and the voltage divider. They both are connected to the same power supply, but that's all. They perform two completely unrelated functions.

Comment: `I am trying to follow the wires on the breadboard and it's doing my head in.` You're discovering why engineers use schematics instead of these cartoons.

Answer (score 7):

[A voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) is simple circuit made of two resistors in series connected to a power source.

This is a simplified version of the circuit you found, concentrating just on the voltage divider part:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpSzuO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the resistors are equal, then you will have half the voltage across each resistor - in the example you would measure 2.5V from ground to A0 and 2.5V from 5V to A0.

The voltage at the center is given by this equation:

$$V_{out} = \frac {R_2}{R_1+R_2} \times V_{in}$$

For the example, \$V_{out}\$ goes to the A0 analog input to the Arduino while \$V_{in}\$ is 5V.

You can rewrite the equation to tell you R1 given the voltages and R2:

$$R_2 = R_1 \times (\frac{V_{in}}{V_{out}} - 1) $$

In the circuit you were looking at, R1 is a thermistor.  Its resistance changes with temperature.  There's an equation that describes that, but I'm not going to go into it here.

You know the input voltage (5V,) the output voltage (measured by A0,) and R2 (10k.)  From that you can calculate the resistance of the thermistor and from there you can calculate the temperature.

---

Voltage dividers are basic things.  You should understand them and what they are - as well as what they aren't.  They aren't (as many people seem to think) a suitable substiture for a voltage regulator.

The picture you put in your question is not a schematic.  It is a wiring diagram.  Many times, problems understanding how circuits work come from trying to use a wiring diagram (which is just instructions on how to connect things) instead of a using a schematic diagram (which is intended to show the function.)

Answer (score 1):

A voltage divider is two or more resistors (or resistor-like components) in series. The node between the two resistor elements is at some voltage between supply+ and supply-.  The resistor essentially divides the voltage by the ratio of the v(divided) = V(input) * [R1/(R1+R2)]